# Finding a generating function of the sequence $(2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,3,3...)$

Tags: solution-verification, generating-functions

I need to find generating function of sequence: $(2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,3,3...)$

My attempt so far:
I tried splitting the sequence into 2 new sequences: $(2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,...)$ and $(0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,3,3...).$

Then I found that the generating function for the first sequence is: $(2+2x+2x^2)/(1-x^5)$, and for the second sequence: $(3x^3 / (1-x^4) + 3x^4/(1-x^5)$.

Then the answer is just the sum of these 2 sequences. Is this good?

Comment: The first one looks right but not the second one: all denominators should be $1-x^5$, owing to the sequence being 5-periodic.

Comment: Easier to split into $(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,\dots)$ and $(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1\dots).$ The 1st one gives $\frac2{1-x}$ and the 2nd one $\frac{x^3+x^4}{1-x^5}.$

Comment: I just spotted the mistake, yes it should be x^5. Is everything else okay?

Comment: Looks sound. I suggest putting up your work as your own answer so that you can get rep for it.

Comment: I mean, any generating function which repeats can be written as: $$\frac{p(x)}{1-x^n}$$ where $n$ is the period of repetition, and $p(x)$ is the first $n$ terms.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help!

Comment: No need to ask us, you can just check yourself if the series works using Wolfram Alpha or some other symbolic calculator. e.g [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+%283x%5E3+%2F+%281-x%5E4%29+%2B+3x%5E4%2F%281-x%5E5%29). Although of course that's just evidence, not a proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's periodic with period $5$, so start with

$$\frac{1}{1-x^5}$$

and the numerator is $2,2,2,3,3$, so
$$\frac{2+2x+2x^2+3x^3+3x^4}{1-x^5}$$